# Why when use std::ofstream for binary writing, std::string.c_str() not equal const char*?

Tags: c++, string, binary, ofstream

I want write in file binary data. For that, i use `std::ofstream` with flag `std::ios::binary` and method `write()`. All Ok, if for write i pass `const char*`, but problem starting if i pass `std::string.c_str()`. If in my binary data locate null character (`'\0'`), all data after this will have random value. I don't understand what's the matter. I think, that `const char*` and `std::string.c_str()` are equal - in both cases it's array of char. But in this example it's not true? Why `write()` in `std::ofstream` process `std::string.c_str()` another that `const char*`? And can i write binary data use `std::string`?

I tried memcpy `std::string.c_str()` to new array of chars, but it's not helped.

It's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  try {
    std::ofstream stream1(std::string(argv[1]), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    if (!stream1.is_open())
      throw(std::string("ERROR"));

    const char* str1 = "\x61\x40\x62\x63\x64\x07\x07\x00\xFF\x01\x02\x58\x59\x5A"; //14 data bytes
    std::string str2 = std::string(str1);

    char* str3 = new char[14];
    memcpy(str3, str2.c_str(), 14);
    const char* str4 = const_cast<const char*>(str3);

    stream1.write(str1, 14);
    stream1.write("\n", 1);
    stream1.write(str2.c_str(), 14);
    stream1.write("\n", 1);
    stream1.write(str4, 14);

    delete str3;
  } catch(std::string& error) {
    std::cout << error << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What i get from Vim:
[image: Text]

Case 1 are right - use `const char*`. Case 2 and 3 equal: after `\x00` all data becomes random.

If `\x00` it's end of line, why it work for `std::string.c_str()`, but not work for `const char*`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string - you're using variant 5.

Comment: What you may be missing is that a `char*` has no idea how many bytes it points to. The convention is to assume it's a c string and that it will be null terminated. So anything that accepts a `char*` as a pointer to an array will find the first 0 value byte and assume that it's the end of the array.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux , sorry, misprint, not str4, it's str3.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wonder why it doesn't work for first case with `const char*`? In first case all 14 characters are printed corrected. Even in first case last byte will be `\0`, it's print in Vim how `^@`, isn't it? And how std::ofstream learn differents between  `std::string.c_str()` and `const char*`?

Comment: @Aleks96 If you tell the stream that the pointer points to 14 characters, it will print 14 characters.

Comment: `const_cast<const char*>(str3);` does not do anything. Converting a thing does not change it (unless there's a user-defined conversion that does, but in that case somebody else will soon have your job).

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm only study and can do more silly stuff :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
std::string str2 = std::string(str1);
```

The copy will stop at the `\x00` in the string, because by definition that's the end of the string literal.  Your `str2` will only have 7 characters in it.  Even though there are characters past that, they won't be copied.  You'll end up with whatever junk was already in the memory when you try to copy characters out of the string that aren't there.  In fact it will be undefined behavior.